# Local storage clearing for select users

Tags: angular5, single-page-application

What could cause specific users to have their local storage cleared, but the rest of the users are unaffected? Is it their firewalls? Is it their anti-virus? Browser? Browser version?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The application -
I have a website that requires login. Certain routes require the user receive a token(from the login step) if not they will be redirected to the login page.

The run down-

Two users have come forward and mentioned they couldn't log in. After some trouble shooting and looking at logs I found they were successfully logging in. So I screen shared with one user and I watched the localstorage in the dev console. I saw that they acquired a token successfully. Then they go to navigate to the myorderCards page and suddenly the token is cleared from the storage and they are routed back to the login page. This then puts them in a loop because every time they login successfully I have a return parameter which sends them back to myorderCards which then clears the token etc...

So the problem I am facing is that I can not recreate this issue. I have tested locally and on the published site. I have tested on and off network. I have tested 3 different browsers and even tested on a mac device(the two users in question are using macs) This issue only happens for the two users that have submitted a ticket. Still I can not figure out how the local storage is clearing. the only place that clears the token are the two lines you see below.

Additional Information-
I have tried changing my browser settings to have a high security setting. However, it continues to work for me. I have changed the browser settings to not allow cookies at all but that breaks the entire website.

P.S there are no errors or exceptions to go off of. Either on the server or the browser side.

app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'myorderCards/:id', component: MyOrderComponent,canActivate:[MyAuthGuard] },]),
```

In auth guard class

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const token = this.storage.getLocalStorageValue('mycurrentUser');
    if (token != null && Object.keys(token).length != 0) {
      const exTime = token.expires;
      if (new Date(exTime.toString()) > new Date(Date.now())) { 
        return true;
      }
      else { 
        this.storage.clearLocalStorage('mycurrentUser');
        this.router.navigate(["/mylogin"], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
      }
    }
    else { 
      this.storage.clearLocalStorage('mycurrentUser');
      this.router.navigate(["/mylogin"], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
      return false;
    } 
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is the expiration on the token being generated, and how is it encoded? The primary question I'm driving at is: can this be a difference in timezones between the token-generating machine and the local browser?

Comment: @DevinBurke Its oauth on the server.... Omg that might actually be it tho. Let me test and confirm. I guess its just odd that we only seem to have 2 customers in a timezone that this would affect. but its still possible. Let me test to confirm.

Comment: Well, in case it proves to be that, I posted my comment as an answer. :-) And this sounds insane and implausible, but in theory you might verify that the users' PC isn't set to the wrong date/time.

Comment: @DevinBurke I could kiss you right now. That was it. I am just kicking myself for having not thought of that all this time. How do use the expires in? I would take their local time and add the (expires in) and then what? I couldnt quite figure that part out so thats probably why I used a expires at because ultimately thats what I wanted to know.

Comment: I updated my answer to elaborate on how to implement. You probably store the client-side calculated expiration date in your local storage, and compare to that in the same way you're comparing to `token.expires` now, assuming you have control over the output of your OAuth2 server, or it includes an `expires_in` field already. Also, rather than kiss me, you could upvote my answer / mark it the 'answer' :-)

Comment: lol @DevinBurke if you upvote my question then you have a deal. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your token's expiration time comparison isn't timezone agnostic.

The issue is: If, one way or another, your token includes a time that doesn't provide its timezone assumption, like `9/13/21 5:30 PM` (or epoch format not based in UTC), then it would already be expired to the end user who's 1 hour ahead of you. Etc.

As a solution, you could provide all datetimes in UTC, and even then convert it to Unix epoch to discourage people trying to manually 'read' it in their local time.

But for OAuth2, it's more common to [include 'expires in'](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-response/) rather than 'expires at'. So the body of an OAuth2 access token is typically this:

```
{
  "access_token":"MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3",
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "refresh_token":"IwOGYzYTlmM2YxOTQ5MGE3YmNmMDFkNTVk",
  "scope":"create"
}
```

`expires_in` is how long (seconds) the token is valid/alive. When the client receives this token, they assume it expires that long from 'now' (where 'now' is subjective depending on geography). So they calculate the expiration date/time themselves and store it, which sidesteps the issue of timezone conversion altogether.

Then, for two customers authenticating at the same time, one in New York may store 6:00 PM while the one in Chicago may store 5:00 PM as an expiration date, even though they both expire the same moment.